# Tell `ng test` to ignore TypeScript compile errors

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I tell `ng test` to ignore TS compile errors?

I tried

```
ng test --force
```

but that's not a valid command line option, and using --force is not a good idea anyway.

Does anyone know how to do this? Perhaps there is something in my webpack.config.js file or tsconfig.json file that I can use?

Comment: Why would that be useful? If the code won't compile, the tests are... unlikely to pass. Nonetheless, you can see the options in the docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test

Comment: In some cases, manually generated .d.ts files are out of date, sometimes you just want to run the code without having to manually update .d.ts files.

Comment: you can use `skipLibCheck` in `tsconfig` if your problem is specific for `d.ts` files